# How to list names in a <select> from SQL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql

I need to list names from my SQL db in a  in my view.

- **usuarios** table:

[image: usuario]

- **cultivos** table:

[image: cultivos]

I want to list all the names from 'usuarios' who has a 'cultivo'

- My PRIMARY_KEY in 'usuarios' is "id"
- My PRIMARY_KEY in 'cultivos' is "id_cultivo" and my FOREIGN KEY in 'cultivos' is "id_usuario"

How to list all the names that have tipoUsuaro in 'usuarios' = 3?

I need to do a INNER JOIN?

I need a result like:

```
<select name="genero" class="form-control valid" id="genero" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="Femenino">Esteban</option>
    <option value="Femenino">Estiven</option>
    <option value="Femenino">Lorena</option>
    <option value="Femenino">Steven</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st question**:

I want to list all the names from 'usuarios' who has a 'cultivo'

```
SELECT u.nombre FROM cultivos c INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.id = c.id_usuario 
GROUP BY c.id_usuario
```

**2nd question**:

How to list all the names that have tipoUsuaro in 'usuarios' = 3?

```
SELECT nombre FROM usuarios WHERE tipoUsuario = '3'
```

Comment: Berriel, thanks for your reply. But I need to do that in codeignite, working with the model, controller and view. I'm noob on codeigniter, I'm trying to do my best but I can't do that :(

Comment: Didn't see the CodeIgniter, but you just need to run these queries and read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471522/codeigniter-populating-a-select-input-form-dropdown-with-database-table-data

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

**In my model:**

```html
function obtener_jefes()
{

$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * 
FROM usuarios 
INNER JOIN cultivos ON usuarios.id = =cultivos.id_usuario 
WHERE tipoUsuario = 3 
LIMIT 1;');


return $query->result();

}
```

In my controller.

```html
$data_jefes['jefes'] = $this->cultivo_model->obtener_jefes();
$this->load->view('cultivo_view/agregar', $data_jefes);
```

In my view

```html
<select class="form-control">
<option value="" selected="selected">Selecccionar jefe</option>
<?php foreach($jefes as $row)
{ 
echo '<option value="'.$row->tipoUsuario.'">'.$row->nombre.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```